# How to set default encoding in Dart Editor?

Tags: character-encoding, dart, dart-editor

My HTML5 project has to be fully made in the **ISO-8859-2** encoding. Is there any possibility to set the character encoding in the Dart Editor, or I should use another IDE with the Dart plugin?

And for IDEs or editors with the Dart plugin: Does any IDE or editor with the Dart plugin generate the yaml file, compile the .dart file and make dart.js (for web applications)?

Please help!

Comment: The Dart editor is based on Eclipse, so this trick might work: append `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-2` to the `DartEditor.ini` file. From: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/29511/

Comment: Thank you, but I tried it and the character encoding is still UTF-8 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the eclipse plugins version of our distribution (https://www.dartlang.org/tools/eclipse-plugin/). You should be able to set the file encoding for all file formats expect for dart files. The Dart language specification does indicate that Dart files should be encoded as UTF8. If you work with them in some other encoding, you run the risk of other consumers of your source files assuming that they're UTF8 encoded, and having trouble reading them and / or munging them on save.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be too difficult to edit the project in UTF-8 but have a deployment step that converts the (non-dart-source) files to 8859-2 with iconv or any number of other utilities. But having an HTML5 project that has to be in a specific encoding seems like a very odd requirement.